# Decrypt a private key encrypted with a null-containing passphrase

Tags: c, openssl

I have the following (very simplified) code, which uses OpenSSL to generate an encrypted private key, using a string containing a `null` as a passphrase:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char password[32] = "pass\000word";
    extern FILE *stdout;
    EVP_PKEY *key = NULL;
    RSA *rsa;

    SSL_library_init();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    rsa = RSA_generate_key(2048, RSA_F4, NULL, NULL);
    key = EVP_PKEY_new();

    EVP_PKEY_assign(key, EVP_PKEY_RSA, rsa);

    /* Write the private key to the file */
    PEM_write_PrivateKey(stdout, key, EVP_des_ede3_cbc(), (unsigned char*)password, 32, NULL, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

The encrypted private key is created as expected, but I am unable to decrypt it, neither programmatically, using `PEM_read_PrivateKey(3ssl)`, nor from the command line, using `openssl pkcs8 -in key.pam -passin file:key.pass`.

```
$ od -ta key.pass
0000000   p   a   s   s nul   w   o   r   d nul nul nul nul nul nul nul
0000020 nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul
0000040
```

From what I can see, `PEM_read_PrivateKey` only accepts a `null`-terminated passphrase, unlike `PEM_write_PrivateKey`.

How is it possible to decrypt the generated key?

Comment: Did you try using an actual password *callback* rather than NULL and providing the passphrase? The docs for the cb-argument (and more importantly, omitting it) are pretty clear: "If the cb parameters is set to NULL and the u parameter is not NULL then the u parameter is interpreted as a null terminated string to use as the passphrase. If both cb and u are NULL then the default callback routine is used which will typically prompt for the passphrase on the current terminal with echoing turned off".

Comment: I haven't tried a custom callback function, and the default one, using the terminal, seems to ignore nulls. I'll see if I can whip some custom one and report back.

Comment: It seems to work. Hadn't occurred to me to use the callback. For shame.
I'll try it with my real-world problem, and approve the answer when it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the caller-provided callback to perform your password-provision. The following is utter brute force, hideous, has no error checking, and in no way is exemplary of my coding habits, but demonstrates what i'm referring to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>

int password_cb (char *buf, int size, int rwflag, void *userdata)
{
    memcpy(buf, userdata, 32);
    return 32;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char password[32] = "pass\0word";
    EVP_PKEY *key = NULL;
    RSA *rsa;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    rsa = RSA_generate_key(2048, RSA_F4, NULL, NULL);
    key = EVP_PKEY_new();

    EVP_PKEY_assign(key, EVP_PKEY_RSA, rsa);

    /* Write the private key to the file */
    FILE *fp = fopen("somekey.pem", "w");
    PEM_write_PrivateKey(fp, key, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), (unsigned char*)password, sizeof(password), NULL, NULL);
    fclose(fp);


    EVP_PKEY* rdkey = NULL;
    fp = fopen("somekey.pem", "r");
    PEM_read_PrivateKey(fp, &rdkey, password_cb, password);
    fclose(fp);

    PEM_write_PrivateKey(stdout, key, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    PEM_write_PrivateKey(stdout, rdkey, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

it should dump the encrypted key to `somekey.pem`, read the encrypted key from `somekey.pem` using the same passphrase, and finally dump both keys to stdout. The two cleartext stdout keys had better be the same... And they are:

**Sample Output**

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Hope that's what you were looking for.